# Unlock Samsung Galaxy S Duos (GT-S7562), forgotten PIN code, hard reset is not an option

Tags: samsung, lock-screens

We need to unlock Samsung Galaxy S Duos (GT-S7562), but the PIN code is forgotten. "Forgot Password" options are not visible. There are important files inside the phone.

How to unlock this phone without wiping out all the data?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you set screen lock on your phone, you're asked to setup a back up option as well. On lock screen, it will give you an option for back up options. If not, then the only option is to Factory Reset it. You can also get in touch with Samsung, to see if there's a way to unlock it.